# Excel VBA duplicating rows while changing certain column values

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, duplicates, row

I have an excel file that contains a column that indicates the Fiscal month due date for each part number row line.

I am trying to duplicate rows only if the Fiscal month due date column has the values of "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "H1", "H2", and "FY". I have arrays set up for each of these values ("Q1" array = ["October", "November", "December"].

For example, if the part number has a fiscal due date of Q1, I would like to duplicate the row 2 times (while keeping the initial row) and change the fiscal month value for each of the rows to be "October", "November", "December" respectively. Likewise if it was "H1", I would like to duplicate the row 5 times and change the fiscal month values to be "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March".

The problem I am running to with my arrays is that it is pulling the second to last array value twice. For example, instead of a Q1 duplicated rows showing "October", "November", "December", it is showing "October", "November", "November".

Here is my VBA code that I have made so far:

```
Sub DuplicateRowsAndAdjustTotalValue()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, newRow As Long
    Dim fiscalMonth As String, repeatTimes As Integer
    Dim totalValue As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
        
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Go Get")
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Arrays
    q1 = Array("October", "November", "December")
    q2 = Array("January", "February", "March")
    q3 = Array("April", "May", "June")
    q4 = Array("July", "August", "September")
    h1 = Array("October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March")
    h2 = Array("April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September")
    fy = Array("October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September")
    j = 1
    
    ' Loop through each row in reverse order to avoid issues with duplicated rows
    For newRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        fiscalMonth = ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value
        unitPrice = ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value
        
        Select Case fiscalMonth
            Case "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"
                repeatTimes = 3
            Case "H1", "H2"
                repeatTimes = 6
            Case "FY24"
                repeatTimes = 12
            Case Else
                repeatTimes = 1
        End Select
        
        If fiscalMonth = "Q1" Then 'Q1
            ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = unitPrice / repeatTimes
            ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = q1(0)
            For i = 1 To repeatTimes - 1
                ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = q1(j)
                ws.Rows(newRow).Copy
                ws.Rows(newRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                j = j + 1
            Next i
            j = 0
        End If
        
        If fiscalMonth = "Q2" Then   'Q2
            ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = unitPrice / repeatTimes
            ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = q2(0)
            For i = 1 To repeatTimes - 1
                ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = q2(j)
                ws.Rows(newRow).Copy
                ws.Rows(newRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                j = j + 1
            Next i
            j = 0
        End If
        
        If fiscalMonth = "Q3" Then    'Q3
            ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = unitPrice / repeatTimes
            ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = q3(0)
            For i = 1 To repeatTimes - 1
                ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = q3(j)
                ws.Rows(newRow).Copy
                ws.Rows(newRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                j = j + 1
            Next i
            j = 0
        End If
        
        If fiscalMonth = "Q4" Then    'Q4
            ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = unitPrice / repeatTimes
            ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = q4(0)
            For i = 1 To repeatTimes - 1
                ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = q4(j)
                ws.Rows(newRow).Copy
                ws.Rows(newRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                j = j + 1
            Next i
            j = 0
        End If
        
        If fiscalMonth = "H1" Then     'H1
            ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = unitPrice / repeatTimes
            ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = h1(0)
            For i = 1 To repeatTimes - 1
                ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = h1(j)
                ws.Rows(newRow).Copy
                ws.Rows(newRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                j = j + 1
            Next i
            j = 0
        End If
        
        If fiscalMonth = "H2" Then       'H2
            ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = unitPrice / repeatTimes
            ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = h2(0)
            For i = 1 To repeatTimes - 1
                ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = h2(j)
                ws.Rows(newRow).Copy
                ws.Rows(newRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                j = j + 1
            Next i
            j = 0
        End If
        
        If Left(fiscalMonth, 2) = "FY" Then   'FY
            ws.Cells(newRow, "F").Value = unitPrice / repeatTimes
            ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = fy(0)
            For i = 1 To repeatTimes - 1
                ws.Cells(newRow, "I").Value = fy(j)
                ws.Rows(newRow).Copy
                ws.Rows(newRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                j = j + 1
            Next i
            j = 0
        End If
        
    Next newRow
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I appreciate if someone could take a look at the code and see where I am going wrong in my logic. Thanks much appreciated!

Comment: Your order isn't correct, try copy row -> insert -> `.Value = fy(i)` (no need for the j).

Comment: @Notus_Panda Thank you. This was the solution. I am feeling very dumb now lol.